# Input process and type for static uint8_t array

Tags: arrays, static, arduino, byte, uint

I am currently trying to convert an integer variable to the value of a static uint8_t array in the Arduino IDE.

I am using:

```
#include <U8x8lib.h>
```

And I do understand that uint8_t acts similarly to the byte type.

Currently, the array has a set value:

```
static uint8_t hello[] = "world";
```

From my perspective, "world" looks like a string, so I thought I would start with creating a string variable:

```
String world = "world";
static uint8_t hello[] = world;
```

This did not work and gave me the error:

```
initializer fails to determine size of 'hello'
```

If I do the same, but instead change "world" to an int like below...

```
int world = 1;
static uint8_t hello[] = world;
```

I get the same error being:

```
initializer fails to determine size of 'hello'
```

I have been successful in converting the uint8_t array to a string through the following process:

```
static uint8_t hello[] = "world";
String helloconverted = String((const char*)hello);
```

I don't understand the following:

1. How a uint8_t array can have a string-like input and work fine, but not when a variable is involved
2. How to create a string variable as the input for the uint8_t array
3. How to create a int variable as the input for the uint8_t array

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How a uint8_t array can have a string-like input and work fine, but
>   not when a variable is involved

String literal is essentially an array of chars with terminating null. So

```
static uint8_t hello[] = "world";
```

Is essentially

```
static uint8_t hello[] = {'w','o','r','l','d','\0'};
```

Which is also a normal array copy initialization, and the size needed is auto-deduced from the value, this is why you can use [] and not [size]

> How to create a int variable as the input for the uint8_t array

Since size of `int` is known at compile time you could create an array of size of `int` and copy `int` value to it byte by byte with `memcpy`:

```
int world = 1;
static uint8_t hello[sizeof(world)];
memcpy(hello, &world, sizeof(hello));
```

> How to create a string variable as the input for the uint8_t array

You need to know the length of the `String` beforehand so you can create an array big enough to fit the `String` value:

```
String world = "Hello"; // 5 chars
static uint8_t hello[5];
world.toCharArray((char *)hello, sizeof(hello));
```

Depending on what you need, you might want to also handle terminating null.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This makes sense and is what I was looking for. Just one more question. Would it make a difference if the variable were to change throughout the program? Let's say I've got a temperature sensor attached to the Arduino which outputs an int of the temperature. From my understanding, I would normally just simply get it to change the variable, but you stated that the "size of int is known at compile time" making me believe that this is not possible.

Comment: @LachlanEtherton No, the size of `int` doesn't change, so if you create an array to hold an `int` as a byte sequence you can change `int` value later and just `memcpy` it again, it will still be the same size.

Comment: Cool. Thanks @Killzone. Appreciate the help.

Comment: When trying the int process following the same way I did the String, I get these issues. Outside of `loop()` I get an error on the memcpy line saying `expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token`. When putting this inside `loop()`, I don't get an error, however when I try `Serial.println(int((const char*)hello));` or `Serial.println(int((uint8_t*)hello));`, I get the value 1073488876. I have looked at the size and it is saying it is 4 bytes. Interestingly enough, if I comment out the `memcpy` line I get the same result, so it must not be doing the right thing with it.

Comment: Regarding the string code, if I paste your code directly, without placing it inside setup() or loop() I get world does not name a type. After doing some reading, I realised line world... must go in a function, so I put it in loop() and it gave me `invalid conversion from uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]` I don't know if it is the Arduino IDE @Killzone, my lack of coding skills, my inability to understand what you posted or a combination leading to these issues...

Comment: @LachlanEtherton For the second try `world.toCharArray((char *)hello, sizeof(hello));`. For the first, you are converting  pointer to `int` here `int((uint8_t*)hello)`, I don't know why you want to do this, or what you are trying to do. I am sorry but you will need to post a new question and state what you are trying to do and what you have attempted and what doesn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Okay @Killzone. Will try your suggestion and post a new question if I have problems. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Here is the link to the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52328494/int-variable-input-error-for-static-uint8-t-array