# Int variable input error for static uint8_t array

Tags: arrays, static, arduino, int, uint8t

This is an extension from [Input process and type for static uint8_t array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52289439/input-process-and-type-for-static-uint8-t-array) regarding issues experienced from the suggested solution.

Currently, I am trying to create both a `int` variable and a `string` variable with is inputted into a `static uint8_t array` and then is printed using `Serial.println`.

I am using:

```
#include <U8x8lib.h>
```

**Int Variable Code (Has Error):**

```
int world = 1;
static uint8_t hello[sizeof(world)];
memcpy(hello, &world, sizeof(hello));
```

If I copy this directly and paste it into the IDE outside of both `loop()` or `setup()`, I get the following error:

```
    memcpy(hello, &world, sizeof(hello));
       ^
exit status 1
expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
```

After doing some reading about this issue, I discovered that this must be put in `loop()`, so I did. The result was that no issues were present when compiling and uploading, however it was printing the value 1073488876 when I added the line:

```
Serial.println(int((uint8_t*)hello));
```

I also did:

```
Serial.println(sizeof(hello));
```

And it printed 4, which means the code is detecting the variable "hello" as being an int (as an int is 4 bytes).

Interestingly enough, if I comment out the memcpy line I get the same result, being 1073488876, so the code is somehow "ignoring" the line when placed in the `loop()` function.

**String Variable Code**

```
String world = "Hello"; // 6 chars including \0
static uint8_t hello[6];
world.toCharArray((char *)hello, sizeof(hello));
```

If I copy this directly and paste it into the IDE outside of both `loop()` or `setup()`, I get the following error:

```
 world.toCharArray((char *)hello, sizeof(hello));
 ^
exit status 1
'world' does not name a type
```

If I put the line `world.toCharArray((char *)hello, sizeof(hello));` in `loop()`, it works.

Serial print also works with the line:

```
  Serial.println(String((char *)hello));
```

I don't know if this has any relationship to my issue with the Int Variable code, but thought I might as well show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I copy this directly and paste it into the IDE outside of both
>   loop() or setup(), I get the following error:

The space outside functions could be used for declaration of functions, variables and classes but not for the execution of the code, it has to go inside functions. `loop()` and `setup()` are functions called from main function, this is why it works and doesn't work outside of them.

> it was printing the value 1073488876 when I added the line:

`hello` was declared as an array `hello[sizeof(int)]`. Arrays have tendency to decay to the pointer to its first element. When you pass `(uint8_t *)hello` to the [functional cast expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) `int(...)` and converting the array `hello` to the pointer to its first element explicitly with `(uint8_t *)` casting, it could have been done for you automatically. `int(hello)` or `int((uint8_t *)hello)` are basically the same. `int(...)` is a cast, as mentioned above, that turns your pointer `uint8_t *` into `int` so the value you see is memory address of the first element presented as `int`.

If you want `println` to print 1 you could convert the array of bytes back into `int` the same way you converted it to array:

```
int world = 1;
static uint8_t hello[sizeof(world)];
memcpy(hello, &world, sizeof(hello));

//convert back
int world2;
memcpy(&world2, hello, sizeof(world2));

//print
Serial.println(world2);
```

Comment: It works @Killzone. I just had a question regarding the memory location process. The `&` symbol defines the memory location of a variable. I see that you use `&world2` when converting back, but not for hello when initially making the variable `hello` the value of `world`. To me it looks inverse. Why aren't all the variables in the `memcpy` lines given a `&` at the start or why isn't it consistent? I assume it has something to do with the conversion back to an int. I have tested the idea of putting an `&` at the front of `hello`, `world` and `world2` and it does not make a difference.

Comment: @LachlanEtherton In short `memcpy` takes pointers for two arguments and `hello` is array decaying to pointer as I tried to explain in my answer. I think you need to read on about C arrays and pointers, you cannot skip that class if you want to learn further :)